# Code executes fine but does not apply to movieclips

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, flash-cc

I am trying to convert a flash as3 game to HTML5 using Adobe Flash CC.

I have attached the fla file. In the game at first run the game works fine. When the next button is pressed the same function which ran well first is executed again but this time the code doesn't work at all. I have set 2 movieclips named Scale3 and Scale5 to visible false and the code runs smoothly without errors but the movieclips remain visible??? Please help I'm stuck. This is my first game conversion. Please help.

[Here is the link to the original fla file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FGgmaoO8LbMG1iUzRYeVVOUkk/view?usp=sharing)

```
var parentMC = this;
parentMC.CurrRailNo = 1;
parentMC.TotalRailsUsed = 0;
parentMC.TotalRailsRqrd = 0;
parentMC.TotalScore = 0;
parentMC.GameLevel = 1;

parentMC.SectionCount = 0;
parentMC.NoOfSectionsToHide = 1;
parentMC.Section = [];
parentMC.HiddenSectionArray = [];
parentMC.StartIndexArray = [];
parentMC.AnsArray = [];
parentMC.NoOfLives = 0;
parentMC.ShuffleArray = [];

GameStart();
function GameStart()
{
    parentMC.Section = [];
    parentMC.ShuffleArray = [];
    parentMC.TotalRailsUsed = 0;
    parentMC.TotalRailsRqrd = 0;
    if(parentMC.GameLevel > 3)
    {
        parentMC.gotoAndStop(parentMC.currentFrame+1);
    }
    else
    {       
        parentMC.LevelText.text = String(parentMC.GameLevel);
        parentMC.GameMC.gotoAndStop(parentMC.GameLevel-1);
        parentMC.SectionCount  = 0;
        switch(parentMC.GameLevel)
        {
            case 1:         
                    parentMC.SectionCount  = 7;                 
                    parentMC.NoOfSectionsToHide = 1;
                    parentMC.Section = [0,3,1,4,1,7,3,5];
                    parentMC.ShuffleArray = [3,5,7];        
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale3.visible = false;
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale5.visible = false;
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale7.visible = false;
                    break;

            case 2: parentMC.NoOfSectionsToHide = 1;
                    parentMC.Section =  [0,3,5,7,3,10];
                    parentMC.SectionCount  = 5;
                    parentMC.ShuffleArray = [3,5];
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale3.visible = false;
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale5.visible = false;                                   
                    break;
            case 3:
                    parentMC.NoOfSectionsToHide = 2;
                    parentMC.Section =  [0,4,3,3,3,8,3,4];
                    parentMC.ShuffleArray = [3,5,7];
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale3.visible = false;
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale5.visible = false;
                    parentMC.GameMC.Level.Scale7.visible = false;
                    parentMC.SectionCount  = 7;
                    break;
        }
        if(parentMC.GameLevel == 1)
        {
            parentMC.nextBTN.addEventListener("click", goNext);
        }
    }
}

function goNext()
{
    debugger;
    parentMC.GameLevel=parentMC.GameLevel+1;
    GameStart();
}
```

In the GameStart() function the case 2 inside switch executes without errors but the movieclips Scale3 and Scale5 remain visible. Any code that is written doesn't apply at all. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Please provide a html5/CSS/javascript code of your conversion.

Comment: This code is the javascript code. CreateJS it is.

Comment: I mean, I need the Html that you kept, for the game..... the very first line say `var parentMC = this;`.which element are you referring to??

Comment: I am using Adobe flash cc to convert the game. In flash we write code in timeline so in my code this refers to the timeline where all the graphics are placed. All the elements on the timeline can be accessed like this.

Comment: Here is the html and javascript files - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_n58nBM70z5c2cyblV0Z1d3cDg&usp=sharing

Comment: I know this might be a silly comment, but have you tried this: Keep the case 2 code block in the next line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102124/discussion-between-maddy-and-dvenkatsagar).